# SharePoint List form to Accept Multiple Items

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-list, list-form

[image]

I would like to do something like above where I can have my default new item form repeat when prompted by a "+" button. My existing new item form is pretty basic with the addition of just cascading dropdowns using SPServices jquery.

Any thoughts on how I can best approach this problem?

To be frank, I have very little SharePoint or JavaScript experience. I'm just taking bits that I'm finding online and trying to piece them together into something I can use.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this : http://stratusforms.com/

Its a free SharePoint Forms JavaScript Library that have the feature you are looking for, just follow the steps explained to implement the form for your custom list and you are done !